# Make a new variable based on conditions and matching with existing ones

Tags: r, dplyr, match

My dataset consists of the variables: day, time, species, diet

'diet' was only recorded at some of the 'times' of each 'day', therefore, I wish to create a new variable 'daily.diet' where the value is 'diet' for each day for each species (i.e. daily.diet = diet when the days and species match).

I made an example dataframe to work with:

```
df <- data.frame(day = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
                  time = c(5,6,7,9,5,7,9,5,9), 
  species = c('a','b','c','c','c','b','a','a','b'),
  diet=c('na', 'na', 'green', 'na', 'na', 'blue', 'na', 'na', 'na'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @Michael Dewar, you might want to consider using `NA` for missing data, unless your coding scheme/data collection steers you otherwise for good reason.

Also using `tidyverse`, you could you `fill` from `tidyr` to fill in `diet` values where missing, in rows where the `day` and `species` are the same.

For example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df$diet <- replace(df$diet, df$diet == 'na', NA)

df %>%
  group_by(day, species) %>%
  fill(diet, .direction = "downup")
```

The example data does not include instances where this might occur. Here is an example with different data to demonstrate, and creates a new column `daily.diet`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(day, species) %>%
  mutate(daily.diet = diet) %>%
  fill(daily.diet, .direction = "downup")
```

**Output**

```
    day  time species diet  daily.diet
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr> <chr>     
1     1     5 a       NA    NA        
2     1     6 b       NA    NA        
3     1     7 c       green green     
4     1     9 c       NA    green     
5     2     5 c       NA    NA        
6     2     7 b       blue  blue      
7     3     9 a       red   red       
8     3     5 a       NA    red       
9     3     9 b       NA    NA
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(day = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), time = c(5, 
6, 7, 9, 5, 7, 9, 5, 9), species = c("a", "b", "c", "c", "c", 
"b", "a", "a", "b"), diet = c(NA, NA, "green", NA, NA, "blue", 
"red", NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for, my guess is you want something like

```
library(tidyverse)
new_df <- df %>% 
    group_by(species, day) %>% 
    filter(n_distinct(diet) == 1) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    distinct(day, species, daily.diet = diet)
```

You could use `df %>% left_join(new_df)` to join it back to your original data.

Also, you probably want to use `NA` instead of `'na'`.  The latter is just a character string, while the former is R's special value for missing.

Comment: This solution makes sense but when I ran it, the output was:# A tibble: 0 x 3
# ... with 3 variables: date <chr>, species <fct>, Rdo <dbl>

Comment: My code assumes that you have already created `df` using the command from your question.  Is it possible that your `df` was something else?